# What I must configure for REST API access to postgreSQL database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest

My source code:
https://github.com/lphquy/mapWithChatRoom

I created 2 table in my postgreSQL: ***profile_users*** and ***profile_messages***:

[image]

[image]

and I wrote 2 REST API to get all things in these table (code in file app.js):

[image]

[image]

I created **getUsers** function before and it's working untill now.

I created **getMessages** function in the current.

But, the RESTAPI: '/users' with **getUsers** function => always running.

the RESTAPI: '/messages' with **getMessages** function => it's not run.

When I use browser to check the 2 api, "/users" always run.

[image]

But, with API "/messages" what I received is nothing and the browers loading permanent.

[image]

So, what I forget?

Thank you.